# Is it possible to change ruby comment symbol?

Tags: ruby, comments

So, to comment in ruby, you need the # symbol.

```
# this is some comments
```

Which is fine, but for multi-line comments, ruby has an ugly system.

```
=begin
    comment line 1
    comment line 2
=end
```

I have search around the internet and found nothing on the topic. I want to see if I am able to change that format to something better by defining my own commenting system. Such as:

```
/*
    comment line 1
    comment line 2
*/
```

I want to see if I can do something like

```
def /*
  define comment logic
end
def */
  define comment logic
end
```

Just something to that effect. I don't need to replace to current one, just want to see how I can define my own. I'm not looking to rewrite ruby. I just want to see if there is something simple that i can do whenever I write ruby. As an example, if I want to add a method to the String class, I can do

```
class String
    def new_method
        # some new functionality.
    end
end
```

I want to see if I can do something like that for comments.

Comment: I am pretty sure that  `/*` or `*/` is never going to be interpreted as a method call in ruby, so I don't think anything like that is going to work.

Comment: i was just giving an example. I just want to see if I can change the current ruby multi-line commenting syntax.

Comment: You can surely write a Ruby-like language from scratch that behaves like Ruby except for the comment syntax. How deep is the level of hacking that you have in mind? Unless you specify that, your question makes no sense.

Comment: I can't think of any way to change the ruby multi-line commenting syntax.

Comment: I'm not looking to hack too deep, just something simple that I can add whenever I'm writing ruby. Just like adding a new method to the String class.

Comment: Then, the answer is **obviously**, no. How would you ever think it is possible?

Comment: Usually these dreams run into conflict with the spirit and philosophy of the language. Just as Ruby uses `#` for comments, C uses `#` for pre-compiler directives and trying to change that would only make your code difficult to use. Try not to invent your own quirky dialect of Ruby, do your best to be a native speaker and your code will be better understood by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody uses multi-line syntax. People do this instead:

```
# comment line 1
# comment line 2
```

Most editors have a shortcut that allows one to comment in multiple lines easily. You will get used to it!

Comment: For sure. SublimeText, just one of the common editors there, can easily toggle commenting on or off for multiple lines with a single shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

A comment says "Ruby stops here, what follows is outside of Ruby". Therefore, it should be pretty obvious, that you cannot change what a comment is from *inside* Ruby.

But there's another problem with your proposed syntax: it is already valid Ruby. It's a multi-line `Regexp` literal. (Yes, it is *semantically* invalid, but it *is* a syntactically valid `Regexp` literal.)